# How can I validate an HTML code inside a text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a textarea inside my web, and the idea is that the user can write HTML code there. So then I would like to "validate" that code and confirm to the user that it's OK.

Maybe this could be done with jQuery? But I've only seen form validation. I want to validate any type of HTML code.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with validate? Just that it has to be valid code, or you want to sanitize the HTML entered?

Comment: I would suggest posting the textarea value to the server (_using Ajax_) and validate the markup there. What language do you use server-side?

Comment: I just want to check if the sintax is ok. I can do it using Ajax, I use PHP on my server, but the problem is the same, how will I validate that on PHP?

Comment: I use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3189029

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to validate html I would go for an online api. It seems that w3.org has an online api + there are libraries available in different languages to validate by w3.org standards. Information about the online w3.org api can be found here http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html

W3.org validation is implemented in different languages:

[WebService::Validator::HTML::W3C](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WebService-Validator-HTML-W3C/) in Perl, by Struan Donald.

[Services_W3C_HTMLValidator](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_W3C_HTMLValidator) in PHP, a PEAR library by Brett Bieber.

[C# library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/w3cmarkupvalida/) by María Eugenia Fernández Menéndez.

[Java client](http://www.rexsl.com/rexsl-w3c/) by the ReXSL.com team.

[Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py_w3c/) library by Kazbek Byasov.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/peterjwest/html_validator.
I think, something like this is what you are looking for.

It is a html parser library written in js.